# Smart indexing for matching values in Julia

Tags: indexing, julia

Suppose I have the following:

```
# valuesToFind: n x 1 vector
# allValues: m x n matrix, in which every column allValues[:,i]
# contains among it's components exactly 1 instance of the
# corresponding value valuesToFind[i] at some row position
```

I am trying to determine the position (row index) at which this match occurs for every value in `valuesToFind` and, currently, I achieve it with the following loop:

```
idx=Array(Int16, length(valuesToFind))
for (i, v) in enumerate(valuesToFind)
    idx[i] = findfirst(articleIDs[:,i], v)
end
```

Is it possible to do this without loop in a single statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for:

```
[findfirst(allValues[:,i], v) for (i,v) in enumerate(valuesToFind)]
```

?
I'm not 100% convinced this is clearer (in terms of code readability) then a simple loop, but it would do the job in one line if that's what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
map(x->ind2sub(allValues,x)[1],findin(allValues,valuesToFind))
```

This is a one-line solution to get the row number of each value in the column. Note that it uses the assumption laid out in the question (unique value in each column). It also uses some assumption on the column first layout of a matrix. The layout assumption can be removed with a `sort` on the first index returned by `ind2sub`.